# Why does my voltmeter trip the breaker

Tags: current

On a single residential 120V circuit, I have two single pole switches in a dual box.  If I try to measure volts between the two hot poles of the switches (don't ask why), I get the big blue flash, and the GFCI at the front end of the circuit trips (and the 20Amp breaker too).  This does not make sense to me since voltmeters are supposed to have infinite resistance and also volts at two different points on the same phase should be zero (approx. if nothing else is seriously going on the circuit).  Why do I get the flash/trip?

Comment: Obviously you're using the voltmeter in a way where it does not have a high resistance (it will never be infinite BTW, 10 M ohm is a more realistic value). The symptoms indicate that you're using it in current measurement mode. Are you using the proper connections on your voltmeter ? What voltmeter are you using.

Comment: Either your multimeter is of terrifyingly low quality or you have it in ammeter mode. Either way, it might be very broken now, and you should not use it until you have verified that it is still operating properly.

Comment: In the manual that came with your DVM, check the *Specifications* section under *Measurement Category*. If it says Category II, III, or IV it should be OK to measure 120VAC single-phase power mains in VAC mode. But if all it says is "Category I" or doesn't specify, **That DVM is not safe to test 120VAC power**.  See National Instruments [What are Measurement Categories (CAT I, CAT II, etc...)?](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/5019/en/)

Comment: You can verify it's operation by doing a simple and safe measurement like measuring the voltage of a 9 V battery. Make sure it's not a dead battery of course.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps (seems unlikely) the meter has a MOV or gas discharge overvoltage protection device that is rated too low or faulty.

It is possible that there is 240V AC between points in the wiring if there are 240V outlets in use and this exceeds a perfectly functional overvoltage device suitable for 115V testing (but rated below 240V).  I have used a meter with an over voltage spark gap that has occasionally triggered (spark sound is audible as a quiet snap) if measuring voltages close to the rated limits of the meter (over 460V DC for my meter rated for 500V DC use).

More likely the meter has the probes in the current measurement terminals and is presenting nearly a dead short to the mains.  These terminals are not always fused because a high speed fuse with a safe interruption rating is larger and more expensive than a cheap glass fuse (and the value of the rest of the test meter).  If it was fused the fuse would have opened on the first test, as it is not it is causing a lot of stress to the device every test and may easily damage it due to over-range input.  Also if you happen to test where a circuit breaker is not there to protect you the meter may fail catastrophically and this can sometimes result in serious injury.

A picture of the test setup showing the type of meter is needed for further analysis.

**EDIT:**
With the exception of the big flash, testing supposed to be across the live terminals and inability to know the type of circuit breaker that has tripped it is unlikely that the trip has occured due to an Earth-leakage circuit breaker (ELCB), residual-current device (RCD), or residual-current circuit breaker (RCCB.  This type of protective circuit breaker operates on much lower currents and could theoretically be tripped by a perfectly functioning but very low specification voltmeter or an out of specification meter if connected from a live to a ground.